# Clearing time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing an issue of clearing the time interval for my image slider.
As I am clicking on the next thumbnail then the previous timer to be cleared and if am selecting the previous image then the previous selected timer to be cleared. Am using color code for timer for better understanding.

Here is my demo

http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9c/27

Comment: Are you saying that once you've clicked you want to completely stop the automatic image cycling?

Comment: @nnnnnn: No, but i want to just want to show that on click the selected image should be shown from that the image cycling to be start. If am selecting the 2nd image then it should start from 3rd, If the timer is on image 3rd, if am selecting 2nd then it should go to 2nd and the cycle will continues. But the selected one show the yellow color. and the previous should be come to the normal color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you setInterval, you assign it to a variable, and you then later use clearInterval(variable). So change

```
      Slider();
      timer=setInterval(Slider, 4000);
```

to

```
      Slider();
      clearInterval(timer);
      timer=setInterval(Slider, 4000);
```

Comment: That's not because the interval isn't clearing, but because your Slider() function doesn't keep track of what you've currently selected

Comment: Yes its fine but color for thumbnails as image changes is necessary

Comment: Thanks alot but why its tooking time to load after its completes its first iteration. So after 6th image it tooking to load again the 1st image

Answer (score 0):

Change `setInterval` to `setTimeout`. `setInterval` will repeat where as `setTimeout` will only fire the once.

Comment: I used `setTimeout`, Its the same issue again as `SetInterval`